# Modifying the results of a query with reducer in Apollo

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I am using Apollo to query a graphql server and manage the results. I am attempting to add a field to the return values with the following reducer passed to to the Apollo graphql function"

```
reducer: (previousResult, action, variables) => {
            if (action.type === 'APOLLO_QUERY_RESULT' && action.operationName === 'getExtractionWorkList'){
                return update(previousResult, {
                    Viewer: {
                        listExtractionWorkList: {
                            edges: {
                                $apply: edges => edges.map( e => {
                                    e.node.isSelected = true;
                                    return e;
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return previousResult;
        }
```

I have confirmed that the reducer is returning the updated values however within the component I do not see the updated values. Is there a way to update the response from the server and have it reflected in the local store?

Comment: It may be that you have to go deeper in the nesting of the query and use the `$set` on the `isSelected` property of the node of the edge.
The component which uses the query is updated with the old values?